# How to dispatch events in re-frame framework (clojurescript) in the REPL?

Tags: clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop, re-frame

I am using figwheel,I want to dispatch events manually from REPL.

e.g after my app is connected to REPL

```
(in-ns 'my-re-frame.core)
(re-frame/dispatch-sync [::events/initialize-db])
```

I get following error
"RuntimeException Invalid token: ::events/initialize-db"

How I dispatch those events? and How to see status of app in REPL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's is because I'm using cider with fighweel in emacs and it tries to find conf with clj extention than clj